# How do I concatenate many objects into one object using inheritance in python? (during runtime)

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, superclass

I have the following classes:

```
class hello(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class bye(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

l = [hello, bye]
```

If I do the following I get an error:

```
>>> class bigclass(*l):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    class bigclass(*l):
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there another way to do this automatically at runtime?

I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: I wonder what kind of problem you have, I've never thought about constructing classes with variable superclasses at runtime.

Comment: I am attempting to define data models and controllers for those models through a text like interface where by the users connect the selected set of models at runtime to the selected controllers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the [3-argument form of `type`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) to create the class:

```
bigclass = type('bigclass', (hello, bye), {})
```

Answer (score 6):

Using a Metaclass:

```
class Meta(type):

    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        bases = tuple(dct.pop('bases'))
        return type.__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)

class bigclass:

    __metaclass__ = Meta
    bases = l

print bigclass.__bases__
#(<class '__main__.hello'>, <class '__main__.bye'>)
```